# Iptables TTL and limit bytes

Tags: iptables

I want to prohibit the reception and transmission of all packets whose size exceeds 512 bytes, and the TTL field is more than 30

Do I understand correctly that for TTL it will look like this:

`iptables -t mangle -A input -j TTL --ttl-set 30` ?

But I still need to specify in this rule that the packet does not exceed 512 bytes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that for TTL it will look like this:
>
> ```
> iptables -t mangle -A input -j TTL --ttl-set 30 ?
> ```

No. The `-j TTL` ***target*** is used to modify the IPv4 TTL header field.

You don't want to do that, you want to match on the TTL value (and packet size of 512 )  and then use the `-j REJECT` target to prohibit it.

You need to use matching modules for that:

> `iptables` can use extended packet matching modules. These are loaded in two ways: implicitly, when `-p` or `--protocol` is specified, or with the `-m` or `--match` options, followed by the matching module name; after these, various extra command line options become available, depending on the specific module.
> <sub>Source: [`man iptables`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)</sub>

Simply activate the **`ttl`**  matching module:

> ## ttl
>
> This module matches the time to live field in the IP header.
> `--ttl-eq ttl`  Matches the given TTL value.
> `--ttl-gt ttl`
> Matches if TTL is greater than the given TTL value.
> `--ttl-lt ttl` 
> Matches if TTL is less than the given TTL value.
> <sub>Source: [`man iptables`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)</sub>

and the **`length`** matching module:

> ## length
>
> This module matches the length of a packet against a specific value or range of values.
> `--length [!] length[:length]`
> <sub>Source: [`man iptables`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)</sub>

So combine that and you get for example a rule along the lines of:

```
iptables -A INPUT --match length 513:65535  --match ttl --ttl-gt 30 -j REJECT
```

or

```
 iptables -A INPUT --match length ! 1:512  --match ttl --ttl-gt 30 -j REJECT
```